# Azure Ratecard Api to get VM price

Tags: azure, ratecard-api

AWS provides a pricing api to get cost details of each service. If you want to know the price of an EC2 instance, you just pass the region,instance type(eg:t2.micro) and service code of EC2 to the pricing API and it returns the pricing details. I understand that azure exposes Ratecard API to get the prices. But It returns a huge JSON with all the services. How do I filter based on service type and its attributes. For example, I want the pricing details of Azure VM of instance type Standard_B2S in Central US. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no separate API available for it apart from RateCard, if you need to get the details of particular VM you can use Virtual Machine Rest API. See this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listavailablesizes#virtualmachinesizelistresult).

**GET**

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/vmSizes?api-version={apiVersion}